# Use of GCC's -Wpointer-arith

Tags: gcc, warnings, gcc-warning

GCC documentation says

**-Wpointer-arith**
Warn about anything that depends on the "size of" a function type or of 'void'.  GNU C assigns these types a size of 1, for convenience in calculations with 'void *' pointers and pointers to functions.  In C++, warn also when an arithmetic operation involves' NULL'.

But I cannot think of a usecase where this can be useful instead of creating nuisance.
Any examples?

Answer (score 3):

All of those operations are undefined according to the C standard. This warning is useful for pointing out situations where the code may work under GCC, but will fail with other compilers.